# jQuery DateTimePicker compare selected date with current date

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

When a user selects a date from my DateTimePicker it has the date like 01/07/2021, when comparing to the current day to ensure it's not a date in the past, my check formats the date like 1/7/2021 and then my code throws the error.

In this scenario it shouldn't throw an error as the dates are exactly the same, just for the additional 0's. What am I doing wrong?

HTML -

```
                                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
                                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                        <div id="dateTime" class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

JQuery -

```
    //create datetimepicker
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            sideBySide: true,
            format: 'L',
            // restrict past dates being selected
            minDate: new Date()
        });
    });


        var dateTime = $("#datetimepicker1").data().date;

        // get current Date to check against user input
        var currDate = new Date();
        var dd = currDate.getDate();
        var mm =  currDate.getMonth()+1;
        var yyyy = currDate.getFullYear();
        currDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

        // check if user date is in the past. If in past then throw error & fail.
        if (dateTime < currDate)
        {
            // throw error
            alert('Error - Invalid Date. All dates must be either in the present or future.')
            $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker("clear");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML too (I assume `$('#datetimepicker1')` is the input field)? What debugging steps have you tried so far? A breakpoint on the line `if (dateTime < currDate)` should help you immensely to determine the problem. Recreating this as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will also make it much easier to help. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do for more info.

Comment: Added the HTML and some additional jQuey that calls the DateTimePicker

Comment: if the purpose of the above code is to ensure that selected data not to be from the past, so why you don't disable the past date into datetimepicker JS lib?

Comment: The problem here is that you're comparing strings, not dates. There are literally thousands of DateTimePicker plugins for jQuery; some of them allow you to get a date object from them, which you can use to more accurately compare with another date object.

Comment: To start with, you need to call `.datetimepicker({...});` on the input itself, not the surrounding div.

Comment: @Onkar `minDate: new Date()` they are, but I suspect there are more things not working than what is just described in the question, so this config may not be working as intended